# is there any webservice to call scan my webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security

is there any webservice. i send web page resources to scan for vulnerability.(Trojen+spy+xss+sqlenjection etc.)Like that

```
Scanner(source)

Scanner(source)
{
      CallService(source)
}
```

OR

```
Scanner(webpagename)

Scanner(string webpagename)
{
   // webpagename: www.xyz.com

      CallService(webpagename)
}
```

Comment: and if it did it with a browser identification string...nice

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.acunetix.com/) website maybe they got an API that you could work with.

http://www.acunetix.com/

Comment: is there free webservice. i have no money to afford 1400 dollars :))))

Comment: They have a free version of the program (http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have an API. You just point it at an IP address/URL and it scans for a lot of common vulnerabilities with web applications.

For a Unix environment:

http://cirt.net/nikto2

There's also a program for Windows:

http://www.sensepost.com/research/wikto/

Which doesn't seem to be related to Nikto.

From what I know, they're both free.